# Landsat TM, ETM+: what are radiometric calibration coefficient of each sensor to convert DN to radiance

Tags: remote-sensing, landsat-5

The Landsat TM Image data that comes with zipped folder contains metadata text file in which all necessary information have been written. In order to further process that data, first DN to radiance conversion required and the method that I read from the landsat handbook [Landsat 7 Handbook](http://landsathandbook.gsfc.nasa.gov/pdfs/Landsat7_Handbook.pdf) is as under:

```
L = ML * Qcal + AL
where ML is band-specific radiance multiplicative factor and AL is additive factor andQcal is quantized pixed value.
```

and these values can be found in that metadata file. But the attached guide [A Straight Forward guide for Processing Radiance and Reflectance_V_24Jul12.pdf](http://cegis.usgs.gov/soil_moisture/pdf/A%20Straight%20Forward%20guide%20for%20Processing%20Radiance%20and%20Reflectance_V_24Jul12.pdf) to convert the DN to radiance table 1 shows the constant values for different period of landsat TM data.
My question here is what are these postcalibration values are and if MTL file contains the values that are different with the values in that table which values should we take for conversion of DN to reflectance.
[Chander et al. 2009](http://landsathandbook.gsfc.nasa.gov/pdfs/2007_Chander_L5TMLUT07_GRSL.pdf) have also mentioned these values in a summarize form.

Comment: Your question is almost all about remote sensing, not GIS. You may find a few helpers here, but may have to go elsewhere.   My suggestion is to consider carefully what quality of output you are trying to achieve, do you need this level of processing? People may be more inclined to help if your application is similar to their own experience. Finally, have a look at http://www.gisagmaps.com/

Comment: And you may well find people here who have used the plugin for QGIS - http://fromgistors.blogspot.com/p/semi-automatic-classification-plugin.html  but lets see if you find this relevant first.